# Wordpress theme changed old theme appears for second

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello I just change Wordpress theme, and now for a second old theme appears. Catche is deleted on Wordpress and hosting panel. Maybe you have answers?

Picture of what happens.
[image: https://ibb.co/X3rhmmn]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a caching issue. Make sure you clear the cache everywhere.

1. From your Cache plugin.
2. Delete cache folder in the wp-content directory
3. Delete .htacess from the root directory and re-save the Permalinks to regenerate the file.
4. If using Cloudflare, clear the cache completely
5. Delete advanced-cache.php in wp-content directory (if available) and re-save settings in cache plugin to recreate it.
6. If your cache plugin has "Critical Path CSS", re-generate it
7. If your cache plugin removes "Unused CSS", re-execute it.

Mention your hosting provider and cache plugin you are using for better answers.

Comment: It was one of the plugin. Thank you amar.

Comment: @Valetas Glad, it solved the issue. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helps :)